# как показать на карте несколько адресов?

Tags: c#, google-maps, яндекс-карты

в программе формируется url

```
string url="www.yandex.ru/maps/?text="+адрес;
Process.Start(url)
```

можно ли вывести таким образом несколько адресов как например в сервисах поиска квартир?
пробовал так

```
www.yandex.ru/maps/?text=Москва Тверская 55, Тверская 31
```

выводит только последний адрес

```
www.google.com/maps/place/москва тверская 55, москва тверская 31
```

ничего не выводит

Comment: Ну, наверно стоит не у нас спрашивать, а у самого яндекса, верно? Например есть [документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/staticapi/doc/1.x/dg/concepts/input_params-docpage/), которая описывает все параметры.

Answer (score 0):

Такую задачу можно выполнить с помощью JS API Яндекс.Карт, например передать массив адресов, поочередно их геокодировать и добавлять метку по полученным координатам.
Документацию к геокодеру можно найти на страницах Яндекса [здесь](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode) и [здесь](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1-dev/ref/reference/geocode-docpage/).

```
function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.765, 37.63],
        zoom: 14,
        controls: []
    });
    var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
        options: {
            provider: 'yandex#search',
            strictBounds: 'true',
            noPopup:  'true'
        }});
        
    var searchArr = ['Москва, Фадеева, 5','Москва, Трубная, 31','Москва, Маросейка, 11'];
    
    searchArr.forEach(function(item) {
    
    ymaps.geocode(item, {
        results: 1
    }).then(function (res) {
            // Выбираем первый результат геокодирования.
            var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
                // Координаты геообъекта.
                coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates();

            firstGeoObject.options.set('preset', 'islands#darkBlueDotIconWithCaption');
            // Получаем строку с адресом и выводим в иконке геообъекта.
            firstGeoObject.properties.set('iconCaption', firstGeoObject.getAddressLine());
            // Добавляем первый найденный геообъект на карту.
            myMap.geoObjects.add(firstGeoObject);

        });

});

    myMap.controls.add(searchControl);
    
}
ymaps.ready(init);
```